# Why is __LINKEDIT sometimes 0x1000 off?

Tags: macos, binary, dyld, mach-o

Parsing an already-loaded Mach-O binary in memory...

Sometimes the string table, symbol table, etc, are where they should be, and sometimes they're 0x1000 off.

For example, I might run my program and `baseOffset + cmd->symoff` is accurate.  Then I'll unit test and `baseOffset + cmd->symoff + 0x1000` is accurate.  `baseOffset` is always valid and pointing to a valid Mach header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at dyld source code...
It's not guarenteed to be 0x1000 off, however, the link edit offset is:
`baseImageOffset + linkedit.vmaddr - linkedit.fileoff`.  Most of the time this difference is 0, but sometimes it is not.

This impacts `LC_FUNCTION_STARTS` (cmd->dataoff) and `LC_SYMTAB` (cmd->stroff and cmd->symoff)

Comment: Because you needed to include the slide. Call `_dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide` with the right parameter (if self, `0`) and you'll get the offset to apply. For reference, it could be more than 0x1000.
The reason is simple: `.bss` is expanded at runtime, and is usually between your header and your symtab / strtab. The exact amount is, I believe, the size of expanded `.bss` rounded up to a multiple of a page.