# MachO LINKEDIT segment offsets wrong by 0x1000

Tags: binary, extract, dyld, mach-o, position-independent-code

Similar to my previous questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61293156/8746647) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60903760/8746647), I am trying to extract dylibs from the dyld shared cache. Though I'm running into a problem, referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34253370/8746647), where the rebase information, as well as other data in the LINKEDIT segment, are being read at the `data_offset + 0x1000`.

For example, when I dlopen the dylib with "DYLD_PRINT_REBASINGS=1" I get the following,

```
TestMachoRunner: pre-load: VoiceShortcutsMod
dyld: rebase: voiceShortcutsMod:*0x103000000 += 0xFFFFFFFF5D8B9000
TestMachoRunner: dlopen(/var/root/voiceShortcutsMod, 1): bad rebase type 0 in /var/root/voiceShortcutsMod
```

compared to when I add 0x1000 bytes infront of the data,

```
TestMachoRunner: pre-load: VoiceShortcutsMod
dyld: rebase: voiceShortcutsMod:*0x121F862F8 += 0xFFFFFFFF5AF3D000
dyld: rebase: voiceShortcutsMod:*0x121F86300 += 0xFFFFFFFF5AF3D000
dyld: rebase: voiceShortcutsMod:*0x121F86308 += 0xFFFFFFFF5AF3D000
...
```

and for reference, a normal library,

```
TestMachoRunner: pre-load: TestMacho
dyld: rebase: TestMacho:*0x1003D0018 += 0x1003C8000
dyld: rebase: TestMacho:*0x1003D0038 += 0x1003C8000
dyld: rebase: TestMacho:*0x1003D0048 += 0x1003C8000
...
```

## Possible Solutions

#### 1. Add 0x1000 bytes of data to everything

Though, while I could do what I did to the rebase info to everything else, this doesn't feel like a good solution because will increase the size of the final dylib by a lot and because it's not certain that it will be by 0x1000 bytes every time.

#### 2. Shift the segment addresses.

In the dyld, every segment from every image is combined and sorted (more info [here](https://worthdoingbadly.com/dscextract/)), as a result when extracting a dylib, the segments have really high vmaddress with large gaps between them. e.g.,

```
1A5747000 __TEXT
1C70492F8 __DATA_CONST
1CB44F160 __DATA
1CD79F3C8 __DATA_DIRTY
1D0014000 __LINKEDIT
```

To test my theory, I set the vmaddresses to be the same as the file offsets, which would make it more like a regular library, e.g.,

```
5B000 __TEXT
5C000 __DATA_CONST
70000 __DATA
78000 __DATA_DIRTY
7C000 __LINKEDIT
```

This, to my surprise, worked and the data was being read correctly. Though this brings up another problem, if I were to do this all the code in the __text section will break because the segments will be mapped differently in memory. I then did a bit more digging and found that when the DYLD Cache is built, it actually fixes this adjustment ([Source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-733.6/dyld3/shared-cache/AdjustDylibSegments.cpp.auto.html)). Unfortunately, to do this, it relies on the LC_SEGMENT_SPLIT_INFO, which is not present in the dylib.

## Conclusion

I believe that shifting the segments has the best chance of working, but I'm stuck on not having the segment_split_info. If you have any ideas I would love to hear them, Thanks!

Comment: So what stops you from adding the `LC_SEGMENT_SPLIT_INFO` to the extracted dylib?

Comment: The split info has data that’s let’s me to shift the segments. Unless It is somewhere inside the dyld I don’t have it

Comment: I know that, but maybe you could modify the dylib executable itself and add it by hand (in a hex editor or something). Some tools exist for inserting LC like https://github.com/Tyilo/insert_dylib so theoretically maybe it could be done for your case too.

Comment: How would I generate it though? The whole point of the segment split info is that it tells me where and how to adjust the file.